# Does Microsoft still continue to support Xamarin UITest, calabash-ios-server, calabash-android-server for Xamarin apps? Non Xamarin apps?

Tags: ios, xamarin, automated-tests, calabash, xamarin.uitest

According to https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios and https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android, calabash-ios and calabash-android aren't supported by Microsoft any more, is it also true for https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios-server and https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android-server?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent/ references https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios-server, are TestCloud.Agent and calabash-ios-server the same thing?

Based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/get-started-with-ios-native), Xamarin UITest is built on top of calabash. Microsoft claims to support Xamarin UITest. How can Microsoft support Xamarin UITest if it doesn't support calabash any more?

We are using Xamarin UITest to test our React Native apps, can we reliably expect this setup to work in the future?

Comment: That's not what I was asking at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my response here:  https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios-server/issues/459

Calabash iOS Server and Test Cloud Agent are the same.

Microsoft has deprecated support for the Calabash iOS and Android cucumber ruby clients.

Xamarin.UITest has not been deprecated. DeviceAgent, iOSDeviceManager, Calabash iOS Server, and Calabash Android Test Server are all required by Xamarin.UITest, and as such they are still maintained by Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you. The docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/preparing-for-upload-ios indicate that "linking Calabash" is required (the link in the docs goes to unsupported calabash-ios library). Do you know why it's necessary to do so to run the apps inside of Test Cloud? Do I need to do the same to run the tests in some other cloud?

Comment: calabash-ios is not a library.  It is ruby gem.  Specifically, it is client for the calabash-ios-server.  Xamarin.UITest is also a client of the calabash-ios-server.  Both clients depend on the calabash-ios-server being embedded in your iOS app.

Comment: I see, that explains it. Thank you.